# Change CSS style from javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css, iframe

I would prefer not to use jquery just for simplicity. I have three websites which one page cycles through. I want the webpages to be scaled each by a different scalar value. I tried applying a class to each page but with a switch statement but it didn't work and it would only stay on the third style. I don't care about efficiency, it's only going to be three pages this scrolls through so it can be hardcoded. Thanks

```
<style>
#wrap { width: 1390px; height: 690px; padding: 0; overflow: hidden; }
#frame.first { width: 1390px; height: 690px; border: 0px solid black; }
#frame.first { zoom: 2; -moz-transform: scale(2); -moz-transform-origin: 0 0; }
#frame.second { width: 1395px; height: 695px; border: 0px solid black; }
#frame.second { zoom: 4; -moz-transform: scale(1); -moz-transform-origin: 0 0; }
#frame.third { width: 1395px; height: 695px; border: 0px solid black; }
#frame.third { zoom: .5; -moz-transform: scale(1); -moz-transform-origin: 0 0; }
</style>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var frames = Array('http://www.google.com, 5,
                       'http://www.yahoo.com', 5,
                       'http://www.ebay.com', 5);

var i = 0, len = frames.length;
function ChangeSrc()
{
if (i >= len) { i = 0; }
switch(i)
{
case 0:
  document.getElementById('frame').className = 'first';
  document.getElementById('frame').className
case 1:
  document.getElementById('frame').className = 'second';
  document.getElementById('frame').className
case 2:
  document.getElementById('frame').className = 'third';
  document.getElementById('frame').className
}      
  document.getElementById('frame').src = frames[i++];
  setTimeout('ChangeSrc()', (frames[i++]*1000));
}
window.onload = ChangeSrc;
</script>
</head>

<body>
<div id="wrap">
    <iframe src="" class="" id="frame" scrolling="no" frameborder="0"></iframe>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It maybe something to do with the page loading and rendering the CSS after the javascript is run.  It may depend on the browser.  Lets hope not.

Comment: document.getElementById("wrap").style.width = "1390px";

Comment: Also, dont use inline javascript include it in a file.

Answer (score 3):

You need break statements to prevent the switch from falling through to the next statement.

```
switch(i)
{
case 0:
  document.getElementById('frame').className = 'first';
  break;
case 1:
  document.getElementById('frame').className = 'second';
  break;
case 2:
  document.getElementById('frame').className = 'third';
  break;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Does anyone know why it will go google at zoom 2x. Then it goes to yahoo at .5x then ebay at .5x zoom. Ideally it would be google at 2x, yahoo at 10x then ebay at .5x. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Your switch statement is failing because it lacks a `break` statement at the end of each case.  Without `break`, the proper case **and any cases below it** will execute.  That is why "only the third one works"